# Finding MacBook power status from command line (AC plugged in, or not)?

Tags: macos, command-line

I want to start some rsync jobs in macOS Sierra 10.12 when the power and home network are connected, I know how to use the `ipconfig` command to check the IP address, but is there anyway to tell whether the power is connected besides grepping the system_profiler? (Which seems a lengthy exercise to get the small snippet)

Comment: `pmset -g batt` shows the state of the attached power source. See if that works for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The pmset command has much shorter output than system_profiler:

```
pmset -g batt
```

The first line on my MacBook says "*Now drawing from ...*" either "*AC Power*"  or "*Battery Power*" when it runs.

Answer (score 4):

`pmset -g batt | head -n 1 | cut -d \' -f2`

You can just use the delimiter to and escape the single quote to get the extracted text.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe help extracted text

```
pmset -g batt | head -n 1 | cut -c19- | rev | cut -c 2- | rev
```

output

```
Battery Power
AC Power
```